# Laravel 4.2 on MAMP 4 - PHP 7.1.0 - Mcrypt PHP extension required

Tags: php, laravel-4, mamp

I've recently installed MAMP 4 running PHP 7.1.0 in order to run Craft 3. Now my Laravel 4.2 installations all come up with a message saying `Mcrypt PHP extension required.`

Does anyone know how to get it working using this installation of MAMP with this PHP version?

Everything I've looked at is related to older versions running php 5.x.

When I run `which php` I get `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin/php`

My .bash_profile says;

```
alias phpmamp='/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin/php'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to install OpenCart using the same PHP version.

I fixed it by using this in my .bash_profile :

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/bin:$PATH
```

And by making sure that in my php.ini located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/conf/ :

- The line 'extension=mcrypt.so' is present and is not commented (no ; at the beginning, if there is one just remove it)
- Every link to 'no-debug-no-zts-**xxxxxxxx**' is using the exact same name than the directory located in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/.

For exemple, mine is :

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.0/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-**20160303**/, I suppose it depends on the PHP version.

There should be three links like this, one at the beginning of the file and two at the end.

I hope it helps someone.